# Integral of $\sin^2(x)/\cos(x)$ - where do I fail?

Tags: calculus, integration

I found that you can do the following:
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos(x)} dx = \int \frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{\cos(x)} dx &= \int \sec(x) - \cos(x) dx\\&=\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|-\sin(x)+C\end{align}$$
However, if I do the substitution $u=\sin(x)\Rightarrow du=\cos(x) dx $ to get
$$\int\frac{u^2}{\cos^2(x)} du=\int \frac{u^2}{1-u^2} du=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{1-u}+\frac{1}{1+u} \right)du=\frac{\ln|1+u|}{2}-\frac{\ln|1-u|}{2}$$
and then obtaining
$$\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos(x)} dx = \frac{\ln|\sin(x)+1|}{2} - \frac{\ln|\sin(x)-1|}{2}+C$$
Then, where am I wrong in the calculations ?

Comment: Are you really wrong? Have you checked your calculation by differentiating your result?

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition is wrong.

Comment: You made a mistake in the fraction decomposition

Comment: Oh, I deleted the comment regarding the missing $\sin(x)$... my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $$\int \frac{u^2}{1-u^2} du \ne \frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{1-u}+\frac{1}{1+u} \right)du$$

Comment: ... the numerator polynomial must be of order less than the denominator ?

Comment: Use $$\int \frac{u^2}{1-u^2} du=\int [\frac{1}{1-u^2}-1]du =\int \left( \frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{1-u}+\frac{1}{1+u}] -1\right)du$$

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you said:

$$
\int\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}dx=\int\sec(x)+\cos^2(x)dx
$$

I think you made a mistake with turning the minus symbol into a plus. It should be:

$$
\int\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}dx=\int\sec(x)-\cos^2(x)dx
$$

Comment: @Barry cipra thanks it's just I'm on my phone and latex is alot harder

Comment: yes, the sign of $\cos(x)$ in the first answer is a mistake...

Comment: @JosephHulme, no problem, glad to help. How anyone can type anything accurately on a phone is a mystery to me. It's always a good idea to look at how things typeset as soon as you've posted; you may have been doing that already when my comment appeared.